# Simplest way to replace a list of values in a data frame with a list of new values

Tags: r, dataframe

Say we have a data frame with a factor (`Group`) that is a grouping variable for a list of `ID`s:

```r
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(Group = factor(sample(5,10, replace = T)),
                   ID = c(1:10))
```

In this example, the `ID`'s belong to one of 5 `Group`s, labeled 1:5. We simply want to replace 1:5 with A:E. In other words, if `Group` == 1, we want to change it to `A`, if `Group` == 2, we want to change it to `B`, and so on. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may assign new `labels=` in a names `list` using `factor` once again.

```
data$Group1 <- factor(data$Group, labels=list("1"="A", "2"="B", "3"="C", "4"="D", "5"="E"))
## more succinct:
data$Group2 <- factor(data$Group, labels=setNames(list("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 1:5))
data
#    Group ID Group1 Group2 Group3
# 1      3  1      C      C      C
# 2      3  2      C      C      C
# 3      2  3      B      B      B
# 4      2  4      B      B      B
# 5      3  5      C      C      C
# 6      5  6      E      E      E
# 7      4  7      D      D      D
# 8      1  8      A      A      A
# 9      2  9      B      B      B
# 10     3 10      C      C      C
```

This for general, if indeed capital letters are wanted see *@RonakShah*'s solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in constant in R `LETTERS` :

```
data$new_group <- LETTERS[data$Group]
data

#   Group ID new_group
#1      3  1         C
#2      3  2         C
#3      2  3         B
#4      2  4         B
#5      3  5         C
#6      5  6         E
#7      4  7         D
#8      1  8         A
#9      2  9         B
#10     3 10         C
```

Created a new column (`new_group`) here for comparison purposes. You can overwrite the same column if you wish to.